# Should I mention about Mentoring students during my undergrad in my CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, cv, mentoring

**Background:** CS Undergrad applying to Fall 2022 PhD CS Programs USA.

I am mentoring 3 students personally. We have short sessions biweekly. This has helped them become better coders and secure internships as well. I also help one in research.

**Question:** Is this worth mentioning in the CV? Does it have any affect to my profile when a PhD Admit panel sees it?

Note: Can we even count this as mentoring? Is mentoring actually a thing when it comes to undergrads just giving good advice to their juniors?

Comment: Is it official, with the sanction of the department, or informal?

Comment: @Buffy's clarification is important, but in general, absolutely! Don't undersell yourself, "giving good advice" is basically all mentoring is and it's an important skill that you've gotten a head-starton

Comment: @ila, I worry about a negative interpretation of "helping", as in aiding in cheating.  Informal, unsupervised "mentoring" might be misunderstood, even when properly done.

Comment: Yes, you should mention it, as well as other teaching related activities.

Comment: It is not department sanctioned!

Comment: If it's not department sanctioned I would be careful how you phrase this to avoid the impression Buffy said. Perhaps you could add "informally mentored 3 students" to your CV and then you could spend a few sentences explaining what you did in your personal statement? Eg "I am dedicated to teaching and mentoring, and voluntarily spent X hours every two weeks to informally mentor 3 peers. I did A, B, C specific things to mentor them." I would also run it by one of your letter writers to see what they think -- they might be able to tell you how to phrase it, or write about it themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This has really helped!